# How to achieve an GPS-Based game like "Parallel Kingdom"

Tags: game-design, architecture, networking, mmo

I'd like to use Google Maps, in my game, much like *"Ingress"*, "*Pokémon GO*" and *"Parallel Kingdom"*.

When I take a deeper look into the Android API/Google Maps API, and dozens of forums, I noticed that it's very hard to display sprites or even animations using the Google Maps API. Someone said that you need to layer stuff. Someone else said it's better to use game engines for that. No one tells me how to begin. I opened Android Studios and made a new Google Maps project. I compiled and ran the app. There is the map, so I guess I have completed the first step.

How do I combine the Google Map with an extra view or LibGDX layer for displaying sprites? How manage this with a multiplayer server?

I am wanting to set my map up like *"Parallel Kingdom"*, which you can see, below.

> [image: Player avatars display their positions on a Google Map display.]
>
> [image: The player avatar displays a range for accessing nodes on a Google Map interface.]

Comment: Hey! Just a small note: you can't ask 'how did they do it' here, as it's primarily opinion based: unless one of the devs come and answer the question, it's only pure speculation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I dont want to know how to every step and every Line of Code. As you said only speculation, what they could have Done.

Comment: I understand, the point is, we don't like "speculations" here :) But you can ask how _you_ could achieve it :) It's a way to try to address _your_ issue. It's a lot more tangible than how _they_ could have done it. You'll get more solutions that you could use, instead of "well they used that super-secret API because the boss of the company was good friends with that other boss at Google."

Comment: Soo i edited the title and added an Main question. Thanks for your tipp ! Maybe now someone will answer me ^^

Comment: The question is broad but I think it could be answered by someone who knows about it. Good luck :)

Comment: Note that many of these questions were still off topic; you have accepted an answer that answers the on topic questions, so I have removed the others. You also go to some effort to tell us about your favourite game.. this is not really the right place for that sort of discussion; especially when it does not tell us anything about your question. I have left the images as examples of what you are trying to do, but I have removed most of the game explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use OpenGL or a game engine that uses OpenGL, then you can make a canvas that's transparent. Then you put the map under the surface view and you draw the sprites on the view.

Calculating the position of the sprites is a bit harder, but luckily Google maps provides the current gps location, so you can figure out how to place them.

You should store the gls location of the entites on ths server and send this to the client (preferably only the stuff around it). On client-side you subtract the current GPS location from the enemy's location and based on the zoom you make it lay between the clipping plane's of the camera.

Comment: Great, Thanks for your answer ! But what if a game of that size got thousands of entitys ? If you gonna loop over everyone to calculate the distance to the next Player its gonna lag like hell :/

Comment: @ganaray look into spacial partitioning, like quadtrees